# I need to start an Activity immediately. how?

Tags: android, android-activity

in a part of my app, I need to start an `Activity` immediately, I mean it should immediately comes up and fills the screen but no matter if it takes some seconds to load the view and widgets(and it has no I/O operations). is there any specific thing in `Android` for such purpose?
for example base on [this article](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/):

> On iOS, the system displays the launch image instantly when the user starts your application and until the app is fully ready to use.

that is about launch time, however. but I want to gain something like that.
I know I should optimize the `onCreate` method and avoid time-consuming operations in the UI thread but I'm searching for another specific way of staring an Activity immediately.

Comment: If you have an activity set to launch in your manifest when the user starts you app then you launched your activity

Comment: Hand off the project to somebody who will optimize the `onCreate()` method and avoid time-consuming operations in the UI thread. Nothing will solve "takes some seconds" otherwise.

Comment: but the Activity which I'm talking about is not a main Activity

Comment: @Soheil so make it your main activity? your question really does not make sense

Comment: If you need to do it immediately, then remove all the code from the onCreate and put that as an async task that you start, then it will start immediately and when all your expensive UI stuff is done it will appear. I'm not sure why you'd want to do that though...

Comment: @tyczj this is not the main Activity and is not going to be! why it doesn't make sense ?!

Comment: setContentView() only and use Looper.myQueue().addIdleHandler(handler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the flow of code is causing you a problem. I would suggest putting nothing in the `onCreate()`. And the layout that has all of your elements set them all to gone. That way when the activity starts, you're given a blank black screen. Then turn all of your layout to visible via code and any of your start up task that were originally in the `onCreate()` can now be launched. You can use a tree observer to determine when the layout has filled the screen to fire something, like a method call or async task for example, to finish all of your loading.